# Fantasy book where main character hunts demons with his master

Tags: story-identification, books

The main character gets taken away from his home by the master. Their main weapon is a staff that he holds in his left hand with a hidden blade in it. 
The back of the book had the message "Don't read in the dark".

There was a girl named Alice(?) with red hair. They only ate a small amount before going out on a hunt. I seem to remember the word "Apprentice" being in the title but I could be wrong about this one.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to the site! Any other details may help this being found, such as when you read it and/or what country you read it in/may have been published in, and any details about the cover

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one of the [Wardstone Chronicle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wardstone_Chronicles) (AKA *The Last Apprentice*) books by Joseph Delaney. Without more detail, it's quite hard to pinpoint a specific book but [*The Spook's Battle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Spook%27s_Battle) (AKA *Attack of the Fiend*), for example, mentions a character named Alice, demon-hunting with a master, a staff with a hidden blade, etc.

> *The Spook was finally satisfied, and we moved on to something he'd
>   only introduced me to a few weeks earlier.He handed me his staff and
>   led me to the dead tree we used for target practice. I pressed the
>   lever to release the hidden blade in the staff and then spent the next
>   fifteen minutes or so treating the rotten trunk as if it were an enemy
>   threatening my life. Time and time again I drove the blade into it
>   until my arms grew heavy and tired. The most recent trick my master
>   had taught me was to hold the staff casually in my right hand before
>   quickly transferring it to my stronger left and stabbing it hard into
>   the tree.*

All of the books in this series bear the legend

> **WARNING:
>
>   NOT TO BE READ AFTER DARK**

on their back covers.

[image]